# Can someone help me identify this coin?

Tags: identification, numismatics, castles, silver

[image][image]

Here are the obverse and reverse sides of the coin. I have tried websites and coin identification apps but no luck. It was dropped into the tip jar at my job and it doesnt look like any coin I've ever seen. No writing, no date. Silver octagon with smooth edges. So curious, help.

Comment: No text = not a coin.

Answer (score 5):

I found out this is an old [arcade token for Aladdin's Castle](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&rlz=1C1CHMO_enUS573US573&q=Aladdin%27s%20Castle.%20arcade%20token&tbm=isch&source=univ&safe=active&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJu_rP2KniAhVQc98KHWAUA7cQ7Al6BAgJEA8&biw=1920&bih=979).

Comment: Yeah, game token was going to be my guess too – no text, fanciful graphics :) You could make this answer a useful hint for others by mentioning how you identified it.